# Listen for transformation changes

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-3d

Is there way to listen for transformation changes? I'd like to get notified when for example a cube has turned. Especially I'am interested in `getLocalToSceneTransform`.

Here is my try:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    final Group root = new Group();
    final Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    final Box cube = new Box(1, 1, 1);
    cube.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    cube.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.RED));
    root.getChildren().add(cube);
    cube.getLocalToSceneTransform().addEventHandler(TransformChangedEvent.TRANSFORM_CHANGED, (e) -> {
        // never get called
        System.out.println("Transformation has changed");
    });

    final Camera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    camera.setTranslateZ(-4);
    scene.setCamera(camera);

    final Timeline turnCube = new Timeline();
    turnCube.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), new KeyValue(cube.rotateProperty(), 0)));
    turnCube.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new KeyValue(cube.rotateProperty(), 360)));
    turnCube.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    turnCube.play();

    primaryStage.setWidth(1024);
    primaryStage.setHeight(768);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

While the cube is turned the `EventHandler` get never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a changeListener to the cube's `localToSceneTransformProperty()` to get notified when the cube is rotated.

```
cube.localToSceneTransformProperty().addListener((value, oldValue, newValue) -> {
     System.out.println("Transformation has changed");
});
```